# Best Site Spider?

Tags: web-crawler

I am moving a bunch of sites to a new server, and to ensure i don't miss anything, want to be able to give a program a list of sites and for it to download every page/image on there. Is there any software that can do this? I may also use it to download a copy of some wordpress sites, so i can just upload static files (some of my WP sites never get updated, so hardly worth setting up new dbs etc)

Comment: belongs on superuser.com

Comment: Are you not able to connect to the site via FTP and download the files that way? If you could do that, it'd be much easier, and you wouldn't have to worry about files being missed because nothing was currently linking to them.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably get lots of opinions.  Here is one: http://www.httrack.com/

Answer (score 0):

wget is your tool.

on unix/linux systems, it may already be installed. for windows systems, download it from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm.

it is a command line tool, with a bunch of command line options for controlling the way it crawls the target website. use "wget --help" to list all available options.